# Apache Solr: Tomcat or Jetty?

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, solr, jetty

I am running an instance of Apache Solr in the Jetty servlet container that came included in the example file download from Apache. I am going to use Solr to set up an enterprise search system that will search across a directory of several hundred files on a local hard drive. Is there any reason I should run Solr in Tomcat and not in the Jetty servlet container that was part of the example? I have heard Tomcat is preferred but WHY? For what purpose do I need to switch over?

Comment: Here's a [discussion](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Discuss-Should-Solr-be-an-AppServer-agnostic-WAR-or-require-Jetty-td3994800.html) about the default servlet container on the developer mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Officially jetty is recommended. Because sole's test cases run against jetty.